# Retrieve new line from a json get with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

So, i have in my database a text for example :

```
blabla
bloblo
blibli
```

I can see newlines if i look my text in my database. This text is from a textarea.

I have an Ajax request for get this text from my database.

In my php script, i do : `echo json_encode($mytext)` and in my ajax success i have my text in the var `data`.

But when i try to display this text data on my page, i loose all new lines. All my text is in on single line.. Any ideas ?

Comment: I guess what you need is function [nl2br](http://in1.php.net/nl2br).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the newline characters (`\n`) aren't new lines in HTML. In HTML you have to add either paragraphs (`<p>`) or line breaks (`<br>`) tags to accomplish this, depending on your scenario. I imagine you need to break line.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert new lines into `<br>` tags using nl2br.

Reference: https://www.php.net/nl2br

Answer (score 0):

User nl2br function to display the data same as you entered in textarea.